# Google Plus share button Displayed Wrong Image

Tags: magento, google-plus

I want to add Google plus button. So user can share products using Google plus. But when i click on share button then Product name, URL everything are correct except product image.
Product image not displayed properly. I write below code for create Google Plus Button code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=my_product_url', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400');popUp.focus();return false">Share on Gogole+</a>
```

I also try to add some meta tags for resolve this issue but nothing happen.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:image" content="..."/>
<meta property="og:description" content="..."/>
```

In sort I need to display current products details and Image on Google plus share popup.

Please help me as soon as possible.

Comment: you have this problem in multi product listing page not in single product right?

Comment: No I have face this issue is Product detail page. When I click on Google Plus button then its take category image rather than product image.

Comment: then you can add the [rich snippet](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) in your page

Comment: I don't have idea about it. So can you please help how can I add that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to tell what was wrong if you gave an example URL but it sounds like you have markup for multiple entities on your product detail page. When that happens the snippet fetcher will take the image from the first entity in the page.

Use this tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets to test your snippet markup and identify the entities the snippet fetcher is seeing.

You should also take a look at: https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/ which shows that we prefer that you use schema.org markup to describe the entities in your page.

Comment: I have the same issue. But when I use your tool, it tolds me everything is right. Here is my share url : https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://www.emmeline.mottet.org/actualite/afficher/8 Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

---

Hello add below code on product detail page

```
<?php $productName = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), ‘name’); ?>
<?php $productUrl = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getProductUrl(), 'product_url'); ?>
<?php $productImage = $_product->getImageUrl() ?>

<a href="#" onclick="popUp=window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=<?php echo urlencode($productUrl); ?>', 'popupwindow', 'scrollbars=yes,width=800,height=400');popUp.focus();return false">Share on Gogole+</a>
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Thanks MagikVishal for your answer but where you used $productImage in you code????